# How to get Bulma CSS framework to work with Laravel Elixir?

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir, bulma

installed Bulma CSS framework with npm. Now I am trying to get Bulma to work with Laravel Elixir. So far I have this in my gulpfile.js :

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir((mix) => {
    mix
        .webpack('app.js')
        .styles([
            './node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css'
        ])
        .sass('app.scss');
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

But nothing seems to work. Any idea how to get it working properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you have to copy it into elixir or require it in bootstrap.js:   https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/how-do-you-include-files-from-node-modules-in-elixir

Comment: Are you wanting to include bulma in your app.css?

Comment: @RossWilson, I wanted to be able to use Bulma anywhere ;) I found a solution. Thank you for yours comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of [retrograde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3111954/retrograde), I was able to understand better the way Laravel Elxir works and I found a solution to my problem. I commented my `gulpfile.js`. Maybe it will help someone else.

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir((mix) => {
    // Retrieve the file from the node_module folder
    mix.copy('node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css', 'resources/assets/css');

    // Compile app.scss and specify a destination
    mix.sass('app.scss', 'resources/assets/css/app.css');

    // Combine Bulma and my stylesheet (filename will be all.css by default) 
    mix.styles(['bulma.css', 'app.css']);

    // Compile and bundle ECMAScript 2015 into plain JavaScript
    mix.webpack('app.js');

    // See Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting
    mix.version(['css/all.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to your solution would be to include the `sass` in your `app.scss` file.

**app.scss**

```
@import "node_modules/bulma/bulma";
```

Then your gulpfile would be:

```
elixir((mix) => {
    mix
        .webpack('app.js')
        .sass('app.scss');
    mix.version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is an alternative indeed. The goal was to use Laravel Elixir though. Thanks!

Comment: I meant using Laravel Elixir to import Bulma.

Comment: @louisfischer ...fair enough